# Abortion and Biblical End Times Prophecy

Tags: eschatology, abortion, signs-of-the-times

Is there anything in scripture (or even private revelation to the saints) which says that near the end of the world, the world as a whole will come to accept abortion as morally acceptable?

Comment: Nope! ....... :)  Just curious, who is making the claim that there is?

Comment: I was arguing with Marc Gravell in [this question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4279/was-the-cold-war-a-rumor-of-a-war) and it got me thinking.  In any event, I'm of the mind that there is a connection.  I'd like to see if anyone with a more robust understanding of the Bible than me thinks so too.

Comment: @Peter actually, I was refusing to engage on the subject. I offered no opinion on that topic, pointedly, twice.

Answer (score 10):

Nothing specific to abortion, although I wouldn't expect there to be. 2 Timothy 3:1-7 gives us:

> 1 But mark this: There will be terrible times in the last days. 2 People will be lovers of themselves, lovers of money, boastful, proud, abusive, disobedient to their parents, ungrateful, unholy, 3 without love, unforgiving, slanderous, without self-control, brutal, not lovers of the good, 4 treacherous, rash, conceited, lovers of pleasure rather than lovers of God— 5 having a form of godliness but denying its power. Have nothing to do with such people.

Which generally points to people being disobedient, which is probably the closest you'll find. The problem, though, is that people have **always** been disobedient and rebellious. Before deciding the above fits "today", first try to find a point in history where it ***wouldn't fit***. And indeed, much of this comes down to simply different ethics (meaning: bemoaning people who don't abide the church's edicts) . Moving away from abortion (too divisive to have a constructive discussion), while "modern" values may sometimes seem at odds with Christianity, I for one thinks today's society is heading in a positive direction, not a negative one, with a lot of emphasis on equality and the value of all humans, even (tongue in cheek) those that don't profess and follow Christian beliefs. And even those that do.

Likewise, looking at Luke 21 10-11, 25-26 - we have **always** been at the mercy of nature. The difference now is that we have much better reporting, measurement and awareness (including awareness of our own harm on the world).

On a more personal note, I don't think obsessing about end of the world prophecy is healthy in a culture. I'd much rather we all got on with living our lives in accordance with our values, and to the greater communal (local and international) good.

So: no, and no.

Comment: I do like this answer and I don't often obsess over the end of the world.  The problem is that you say that this age is not special from the standpoint of human behavior, but it is special from the standpoint of technological advancement.  But what if that technological advancement is exactly what is leading us to behaviors we never before experienced?  Couldn't that make future generations more disobedient and more rebellious until again it is as it was in the days of Noah?

Comment: @Peter and what if it isn't? Frankly, I'm not a good person to ask on that, since my views are secular (and IMO ethical, but not along religious doctrinal lines). Also, while I'm happy to accept there's enough commonality in the various legends to make it highly likely we've seen floods, I don't buy into Noah specifically, any more than I would Utnapishtim, Xisuthrus, Manu, Deucalion, Tapi or Waynaboozhoo.

Comment: "lovers of themselves" and "ungrateful" are as close as you can get to abortion. Keep in mind that abortion was so abhorrent by the standards of that time, that you will probably not find any sources mentioning it. Just like there was no law against patricide in Athene, because, as the story goes, even the thought of such thing did not occur in the minds of the inhabitants.

Comment: @vsz I don't think judging people here is constructive; it is a complex and emotive issue; for people being ground mercilessly between a rock and a hard place, I don't think either of your quoted terms is useful. Frankly, your over-simplification is an injustice to all. However, it is **very** well known even in ancient history, and has always been complex and controversial, but not as rare as you suggest. It is also naive to suggest that patricide didn't occur in Athene.

Comment: @vsz The very fact that it is so divisive is why I tried several times to sideline the abortion part of the question. That is not going to end well. It also isn't something with a "single" Christian view; there are **plenty** of pro-choice Christian groups and preachers, and every shade of view in between.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: I did not suggest there was no patricide in Athens, I was just quoting an anecdote as an example. Before starting to attack me, defending your ideology and claiming that I insulted yours, please take a look at what the question is and what I indented to answer: I quoted those terms as the most likely Bible quotes some might believe are referring to abortion.

Comment: @vsz I did not attack you; I am merely suggesting that it is too complex an issue to say that any action is for purely selfish reasons. It is inaccurate and misleading to claim that the two terms in any way are "referring to" (specifically) abortion; if you choose to categorise it that way, then I can't change your mind - but: be aware that the terminology you use here is demonizing to people who may have had to make a very hard decision. But again, all of this is why I really tried not to get into it!

Comment: @ Marc Gravel: please read my previous comment more carefully. I did not say that when hearing the word "selfish", abortion is the first thing jumping to my mind, and I was not categorizing anybody. I only said that as abortion itself is not present in the Bible, (at least not in parts about the end times, as far as I remember), this is the closest thing people might be using as a reference. Of course it's a complex thing, and of course there are a lot of situations where abortion is purely selfish, and situations where there might no other choice, but this is not the point of this question.

Comment: @vsz I think the line needs to be drawn between the women and men who suffer through aborting their children and the eugenicists who actively desire a world with less undesirable people in it.  They're the ones I'm talking about, whose lack of respect for humanity might be the most evil thing that has ever came about in the history of mankind.  What I want to know, and what I'm fishing for, is how special are these times in connection with a widespread acceptance of abortion on demand.

Comment: @Peter Turner: It depends. Many people would find an abortion more acceptable where the child has very low chances of having a healthy life and it might even endanger the life of the mother, rather than one where the mother is just irresponsible. The last category might fit the "lovers of themselves" and "ungrateful", and before someone finds it offensive: I'm NOT claiming that all or most abortions are like "I just want to party all my life and I'll kill my child because he is holding me back", but I do say that this kind of thinking is now (sadly) more socially acceptable than in the past.

Comment: @vsz How on Earth do you get from "lovers of themselves" to "abortion"‽ I'm pretty sure that it's a reference to masturbation which, unless I have my biology 100% wrong, tends not to result in pregnancy.

Comment: @Kaz Dragon: Maybe "lovers of themselves" means more "egoists" and less "making sex to themselves"?

Comment: @vsz I still have no idea how you get to abortion from there without contorting language so ridiculously that it could equally mean "lovers of cheesecake."

Comment: I thought the "humanity moving in a positive direction" idea sort of died out with the senseless WWI ... was it recently revitalized by the historically illiterate, or are people now saying WWI was progress in the right direction?  Or do you just mean "things seem to be getting better since ___"  (WWI?  The Great Depression?  WWII?  Vietnam?  The Rwandan Genocide?  Obamacare?)  I'm just curious what the logic is there.

Comment: @Jas3.1. [The world is becoming decidedly less violent](http://www.ted.com/talks/steven_pinker_on_the_myth_of_violence.html)

Answer (score 2):

The idea is based on the following logic:

In [Exodus](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%201:15-22&version=NASB) we learn that while Israel resided in Egypt under the oppression of the Pharaoh, God planned to bring a deliverer to His people: Moses.  However, when Moses was born, Pharaoh had issued a decree to slay the firstborn sons.  Moses was spared from this slaughter by the providence of God, and went on to lead God's people out of Egypt.

In [Matthew](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%202:16&version=NASB) we learn that Herod sought to prevent the birth of the Christ by slaughtering all male children.  Christ was also a Servant of God and a leader to God's people, destined to lead God's elect out of the hand of their enemies.

Some conclude that:

- In both cases God was bringing someone to lead His people out of captivity
- In both cases the enemy attempted to thwart that plan through a slaughter of children
- There is a final deliverance that is yet to come (in the end times)
- Prior to that deliverance certain key people will be born which will lead God's people
- Since Egypt is a type of "the world", and Israel a type of "the church", perhaps the slaughter is also a foreshadowing of a slaughter on the generation destined to lead God's people in the end times
- We see abortion happening and it is an atrocity
- Abortion must be that slaughter

Anyway, take it for what it's worth, but that's the origin.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in scripture which makes this statement. As far as private revelation, nothing I know of, however, I do not typically seek out teachings based on private revelation. 2 Peter 1:20-21.

Answer (score 0):

some people think Jesus's words to the weeping women were about abortion.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE. Can you please provide some explanation - who are these people, what is their evidence? As it is, this answer will likely be deleted.

Comment: Or, are you possibly conflating the prophecy of Rachel mourning for her children (widely assumed to be pointing to the Massacre of the Innocents?)

Comment: Either way, this answer needs to be fleshed out...